# How do I find the component position in a functional react-native component

Tags: react-native, position, react-hooks

I am trying to dynamically find the position of my component after it has rendered. Im trying to use useRef and getBoundingClientRect() (see code below).

The response I get is this.

> myRef.current.getBoundingClientRect is not a function. (In 'myRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()', 'myRef.current.getBoundingClientRect' is undefined).

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { View, Button, TextInput } from "react-native";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [value, onChangeText] = useState("Useless Placeholder");

  const myRef = useRef();

  const showRefPosition = () => {
    console.log("button clicked, set focus and log position");
    // this works and shows that i am using the ref correctly
    myRef.current.focus();

    // however, this does not work and throws the eror
    let componentPosition = myRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(`Component Position ${componentPosition}`);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        style={{ height: 40, borderColor: "gray", borderWidth: 1 }}
        onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
        value={value}
        ref={myRef}
      />
      <Button title="Click Me" onPress={() => showRefPosition()} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try **measure** method in react-native.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { View, Button, TextInput } from "react-native";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [value, onChangeText] = useState("Useless Placeholder");

  const myRef = useRef();

  const showRefPosition = () => {
    console.log("button clicked, set focus and log position");
    // this works and shows that i am using the ref correctly
    this.ref.measure( (width, height) => {
      console.log('Component width is: ' + width)
      console.log('Component height is: ' + height)
    })
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        style={{ height: 40, borderColor: "gray", borderWidth: 1 }}
        onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
        value={value}
        ref={(ref) => { this.ref = ref; }}
      />
      <Button title="Click Me" onPress={() => showRefPosition()} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks @firats - that sorted it out for me :). It looks like my main issue was using useRef to set the ref rather than   **ref={ref => {myNewRef = ref;}}**. Not sure why useRef didn't work.

Comment: Just in case anyone else reading this was stuck similar to me, measure can take the following parameters originX, originY, width, height, pageX, pageY. pageX and pageY will give you your position.

Comment: @TeamBeamo Using useRef should be fine. The problem was getBoundingClientRect only works on the web.

Comment: The above component throws an error for me, if I try to use it in my app... The measure method also doesn't exist on the ref object.

Comment: this returns undefined in function component

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet,  Pressable} from 'react-native';
import { useRef } from 'react' ;

export default function App() {

  const ref1 = useRef() ;
  const ref2 = useRef() ;

  function showMeasure1(evt){
      ref1.current.measure(
        (x,y,width,height,pageX,pageY) => {
          console.log('ref1 ',x,y,width,height,pageX,pageY) ;
        });
  }

  function showMeasure2(evt){
      ref2.current.measure(
        (x,y,width,height,pageX,pageY) => {
          console.log('ref2 ',x,y,width,height,pageX,pageY) ;
        });
  }
  
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    <Pressable ref={ref1} onPressIn={showMeasure1} style={{backgroundColor:'orange'}}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
      CLICK ME{"\n"}
      CLICK ME
      </Text>
    </Pressable>
    
    <Pressable ref={ref2} onPressIn={showMeasure2} style={{backgroundColor:'yellow'}}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
      CLICK ME
      </Text>
    </Pressable>    
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

[see code on snack.expo.dev](https://snack.expo.dev/brauhvWKxm3KU90zkwt3H)
( click panel at bottom of screen and then "logs" to see output )

[measure docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation) [ref docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef#manipulating-the-dom-with-a-ref)